# Allow duplicate class name in Maven compile test phase

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit

I want Maven to use a different implementation of a concrete class during unit testing, but the compile-test phase complains about the duplicate class name. Ant did not seem to have the problem. How can I do this?

Some background. I have a large legacy system. It contains a very large nasty class full of static methods, that every other class in the system uses. The design is terrible but that is another issue. Let's call this class com.mycompany.Monster. In order to unit test we created another instance of com.mycompany.Monster that has most of the static methods stubbed out and then compile/link our test classes with the stubbed instance instead of the official implementation. This technique is mentioned in Michael Feather's "Working Effectively with Legacy Code", he calls it "Link Substitution".

As I said Ant handles this fine, but Maven halts when it encounters the duplicate class.

Comment: If you have a duplicate class than the behaviour is correct to complain about that. What do you mean by `Ant handles this fine'? Can you give a full example what you did and what you exepect from Maven? Apart from that the compile of the classes is done by javac which is used by Ant as well so i don't understand that you claiming Ant works whereas Maven does not...

Comment: Creating a small example exposed the problem. It is ok to have Monster.java in both the main and test directories because maven invokes javac for main, and then again for test. It is not ok to have multiple copies of Monster.java within an invocation of javac. In my case my build is very complex and uses multiple source directories that do in fact have individual copies of Monster.java. The Ant script built each set of tests separately, in Maven I lumped them all together. I know how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about tests the class in `src/test/java` should be named like `MonsterTest.java` and **NOT** `Monster.java` as well. What you describes sounds like a not a good architecture and strcuture neither for Maven nor in Ant as well. Follow the conventions. If you have several source folders which means in Maven having separated modules which you don't have and that is causing your problems.

Comment: I may have been unclear. The point of defining Monster.java under the test directory is to provide a different implementation so that other parts of the system may be tested. If you've only worked on well designed systems then this will seem strange to you, but there are designs that are so bad that techniques like this are needed. Take a look at Feather's book.